# How to JSON encode this PHP array?

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have an array `$suggested_cities`, here it is vardumped:

```
array(3) {
  [15526]=>
  string(9) "Alabaster"
  [15137]=>
  string(7) "Florala"
  [37091]=>
  string(8) "Saraland"
}
```

When I json encode this array:

```
echo json_encode(array($suggested_cities));
```

I get this output:

```
[{
    "15526": "Alabaster",
    "15137": "Florala",
    "37091": "Saraland"
}]
```

But I need it to be:

```
[{
    "15526": "Alabaster"
},
{
    "15137": "Florala"
},
{
    "37091": "Saraland"
}]
```

How can I do that? I assume it's a "duh" answer but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: The desired JSON structure represents an array of objects - there's a big clue. Also, it would be better to use two fields per object, for id and city.

Comment: @David Caunt you're right, just had to turn suggested_cities into a multidimensional array. Also used the id as a separate field instead of the key. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
$json = json_encode(array_chunk($suggested_cities, 1, true));
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/3KV1ZlcM)

Though simply encoding `$suggested_cities` seems to be more straightforward.

Comment: This works so I will pick this as best answer, but all I had to do was turn $suggested_cities into a multidimensional array and json encode that.